# Curl request with access token in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, curl

I am wondering if How can I communicate with API with access token header in angular, the Curl request that defines the API endpoints is below

```
curl --request GET \
--url https://**********.net/api/books \
--header '*****-cors: <access_token>'
```

should I be importing and using HttpHeaders module like this?

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
      'Authorization': '<access toke>'
    });
    this.http.post('https://**********.net/api/books',  { headers: headers });
```

Answer (score -1):

Used ajax `getRequest` and added the header to `get()`

```
headerParams = {"auth":"<access token>"}
```

and in the return statement

```
return (this.http.get(this.apiurl,{headers:this.headerParams}))
```